# Method Overload and argument 6 error

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I've revised my code and question to better reflect what I'm trying to accomplish.

Background: I have different layer interfaces as part of my project.

- Service Layer - handles my business logic, validates entries, (the brains)
- Data Access Layer - simply executes the methods or functions it is passed
- Aspx & aspx.cs files where the methods need to take place (i.e the user interface)

Here is my code for the ConnectionTypeSetup.aspx.cs file, I've also marked the line where there is an error:

```
protected void uxSaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var accountTrackersvc = new AccountTrackerSvc(); 

        //Insert or update record
        var result = ViewState["ConnectionTypeID"] == null ?
            accountTrackersvc.InsertConnectionType(uxConnectionTypeDescTxt.Text.Trim(),
                                            CommonSVC.GetUserInfoFormattedFromSession())

  /*Error on this line */                : accountTrackersvc.UpdateConnectionType(DataConverter.StringToInteger(ViewState["ConnectionTypeID"].ToString()),
                                           uxConnectionTypeDescTxt.Text.Trim(),
                                           Enums.GetIsDisabledByItemStatusValue(SafeValueAccessor.GetControlValue(uxStatusDdl)),
                                           CommonSVC.GetUserInfoFormattedFromSession(),"Default",false);


        //Check result
        if(result.Successful)
        {
             uxInfoMsg.DisplayMessage(result.Message, InfoMessage.InfoMessageType.Success);
             BindGridContent();
             uxPopupMdl.Hide();
        } 
        else
        {
            uxModalInfoMsg.DisplayMessage(result.Message, InfoMessage.InfoMessageType.Failure);
            uxPopupMdl.Show();
        }
        // Hide progress indicator
        Master.HideProgressIndicator();
```

The service layer which again handles my business logic is formatted as follows. Please note there are 2 separate methods being used and `Insert` and `Update`:

```
public BO.OperationResult InsertConnectionType(string connectionTypeDesc, string createdBy)
        {
            var operationResult = new BO.OperationResult();

        // connection type description required
        if (connectionTypeDesc.Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            operationResult.Successful = false;
            operationResult.Message += "Connection type description is required";
        }
        //Createdby required
        if (createdBy.Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            operationResult.Successful = false;
            operationResult.Message += "A record has not been saved in the form this entry was created by";
        }
        if (operationResult.Successful)
        {
            operationResult.DBPrimaryKey = new DAL.AccountTrackerDAL().InsertConnectionType(connectionTypeDesc.Trim(), createdBy);
            operationResult.Message = "Account Access Level Saved Successfully";
        }
        return operationResult;
    }
```

2nd Business logic Method and code for update:

```
public BO.OperationResult UpdateConnectionType(int connectionTypeID, string connectionTypeDesc,bool isDisabled,string lastUpdatedBy)
        {
            var operationResult = new BO.OperationResult();

            if (connectionTypeDesc.Trim().Length <= 0)
            {
                operationResult.Successful = false;
                operationResult.Message += "Connection Type Description has not successfully updated.";
            }
            if (lastUpdatedBy.Trim().Length <= 0)
            {
                operationResult.Successful = false;
                operationResult.Message += "Last updated by must be entered.";
            }
            if (operationResult.Successful)
            {
                operationResult.DBPrimaryKey = new DAL.AccountTrackerDAL().UpdateConnectionType(connectionTypeID, lastUpdatedBy,  connectionTypeDesc,  isDisabled);
                operationResult.Message = "Account Access Level Saved Successfully";
            }
            return operationResult;        
        }
```

Lastly, I'll only include the method signitures for the DAL layer as I think that should be enough and not saturate this question with code.

Update ConnectionType

```
public int UpdateConnectionType(int connectionTypeID, string lastUpdatedBy, string connectionTypeDesc, bool isDisabled)
```

Insert ConnectionType

```
 public int InsertConnectionType(string connectionTypeDesc, string createdBy)
```

My current error reads: No overload for method UpdateConnectionType takes 6 arguments. I've tried to default the values only to receive this error. Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the method definition of `InsertConnectionType` ? [Right click on the method signature -> View Definition of method in Visual studio]

Comment: A method expecting 4 parameters can't be invoked with 2 unless you're using default parameters. Not clear for me what you're expecting to be honest

Comment: @now he who must not be named I right clicked and then selected go to defintion (I believe that's the same), but it then takes me to the class holding my 1st block of code that I posted in my question.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  You haven't posted the entirety of the method call, but based on your exception you're only passing 2 parameters, whereas the function expects 4 parameters.

Comment: @user4966755: If that is the case, then you **must supply 4 parameters**.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi If I give the 4 parameters default values then they become optional parameters. Will this change the functionality of my base method at all or will that just be something I'd have to test for?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `InsertConnectionType`, you **MUST** provide four (4) parameters. That is how the method is written, so that is what you must do:

```
accountTrackersvc.InsertConnectionType(
  uxConnectionTypeDescTxt.Text.Trim(), 
  CommonSVC.GetUserInfoFormattedFromSession(),
  "Default", false)
```

The parameters above would pass the compiler.

If you absolutely insist on using only two (2) parameters, you could create an overload method:

```
public BO.OperationResult InsertConnectionType(string connectionTypeDesc, int connectionTypeID)
{
  return InsertConnectionType(connectionTypeDesc, connectionTypeID, "Default", false);
}
```

### UPDATE

To add an overload for your **UpdateConnectionType** method, try something like this:

```
    public BO.OperationResult UpdateConnectionType(int connectionTypeID, string connectionTypeDesc)
    {
        var operationResult = new BO.OperationResult();

        if (connectionTypeDesc.Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            operationResult.Successful = false;
            operationResult.Message += "Connection Type Description has not successfully updated.";
        }
        if (operationResult.Successful)
        {
            operationResult.DBPrimaryKey = new DAL.AccountTrackerDAL().UpdateConnectionType(connectionTypeID, "Default", connectionTypeDesc, false);
            operationResult.Message = "Account Access Level Saved Successfully";
        }
        return operationResult;
    }
```

Of course, make sure you replace the text `"Default"` and the Boolean value `false` with whatever is appropriate for your class.

Comment: I've gotten the InsertConnectionType method to work, do you have a suggestion as to how I'd get the UpdateConnectionType to work. I've tried adding the default values listed but to no success.

Comment: @user4966755 - I added an **Update** section that should roughly handle what you are requesting.