# Is there a default value for the object datatype?

Tags: c#, .net

I have method overload issue, which I've asked about in a previous posting.  After some feedback and research I'm convinced that I need to default some of the values being passed in my method.

My question is: is there a default value for the object datatype? If, so please provide an example.

Here is an example of a defaulted `string` and `int` parameter:

```
public void ExampleMethod(int required, string optionalstr = "default string",
    int optionalint = 10)
```

For a copy of my code please see: [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164552/method-overload-and-argument-6-error)

Answer (score 2):

The only value you can use for the default value of an optional `object` parameter is `null` - or equivalently, `default(object)`. There are no other compile-time constants of type `object`. I'm slightly surprised that you can't use a string literal, given that `string` is implicitly convertible to `object`, but the compiler prevents that :(

Having said all of this, if you go behind the compiler's back you *can* do more than that... you can use `DefaultParameterValueAttribute` and `OptionalAttribute` to create optional parameters of type `object` with string and numeric values. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Test
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Foo(); // Prints 5 test
    }

    static void Foo([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(5)] object x,
                    [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("test")] object y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
    }    
}
```

I'd advise against doing this though - it's somewhat against the spirit of things...

Answer (score 0):

The default for object types is null,
[check](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88470.aspx)

and for the rest check [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Comment: Well, for value types it's "the value obtained by setting all the fields to their default values". `DateTime` is a value type, and you can't really say that the default value of `DateTime` is 0, as 0 isn't a `DateTime` value.

Comment: @JonSkeet My mistake, Mr. Skeet